Hopf fiber is foliation of some distribution.
Consider $\mathbb{S}^3\subset \mathbb{H}$ where $\mathbb{H}$ is quaternions. Let
$$\pi:\mathbb{S}^3\to \mathbb{S}^2$$
s.t. $\pi(u,v)=(2u\bar{v},|u|^2-|v|^2)$  which is so-called Hopf fiber. Let $D=span\{X\}$ where $X=i(x,y)=(ix,-iy)$ for $(x,y)\in \mathbb{S}^3$. Note that
$$\mathbb{S}^3=\bigcup_{p\in\mathbb{S}^2}\pi^{-1}(p)$$
Each $\pi^{-1}(p)=\{e^{i\theta}(u,v)\}$ for some $(u,v)\in \pi^{-1}$ since we can use Lie group action $\mathbb{S}$ to $\mathbb{S}^3$ by $e^{i\theta}\cdot (u,v)=e^{i\theta}(u,v)$ and each obit space is $\pi^{-1}(p)$. We want to show the disjoint union is the foliation of $D$. By Frobenius Theorem, Indeed shows that $e^{i\theta}(x,y)$ is the integral curve of $X$. Let $x=x_1+iy_1,y=x_2+iy_2$, we have
$$X(e^{i\theta}(x,y))=(e^{i\theta}(ix_1-y_1),e^{i\theta}(-ix_2+y_2))$$
and
$${e^{i\theta}(x,y)}'=(e^{i\theta}(ix_1-y_1),e^{i\theta}(ix_2-y_2)$$
i.e. $(e^{i\theta}(x,y))'\ne X|_{e^{i\theta}(x,y)}$. It seems that $e^{i\theta}(x,y)$ even not integral curve of $X$. I think there must have something wrong, but I have no idea.
